# How to query the child views of a parent view using Titanium?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I am looking to create a general purpose routine that will operate over a view's children.  Within the routine I need to be able to iterate over the child views.  I don't see anything in the API that would suggest that there is any way to get the child views.  There is an "add()" and a "remove()" method but nothing like "get()" nor does there appear to be any properties like "views". What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is the basic structure for removing child objects from a view

```
    if (view.children) {
        for (var c = view.children.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
            view.remove(view.children[c]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe something like this answer, and the answer from mkind:
`if (view.children) {
 for (var i=0; i<view.children.length; i++) {
  if (view.children[i] !== undefined) {
   view.remove( view.children[i] );
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 4):

i would check also for

```
if (view.children[c] !== undefined) {..}
```

since i already got problems with android without verifieing.