# Accessing Object value which is inside an Object

Tags: javascript, titanium

```
var Views = {};
```

Views is an Object. Now i add `Views[1].add(TextField);`

How can i access `Views[1].TextField.value`

When i alert Views Object, i get this...

```
{"2":"[Ti.UI.View]","1":"[Ti.UI.View]"}
```

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.6.0/Titanium.UI.View.add-method.html

Comment: do you want to get the value on some click event?

Comment: That depends on how `Ti.UI.View` works. Have a look at the API documentation (from wherever this "class" is) or the implementation, we cannot help you with that (at least not with the given information).

Comment: Please show us the `add` function. And where does `TextField` come from?

Comment: @Felix Kling: That's the add method of Ti.Ui.View Class

Comment: @John-Cooper: Is Textfield an object or a class?  If you're using a standard capitalization convention, the JSON seems to say it's a class.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474953/how-to-query-the-child-views-of-a-parent-view-using-titanium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
Views[indexofView].children[indexOfChild].value
```

Where children is the added element in the view. 
It could be any

- text field
- label

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Views[1].TextField.value, you just want Views[1].value