# Titanium accessing child of a view returns null

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I get null on

```
view.children[0]
```

The view is a Titanium.UI.View-object and has just one child Titanium.UI.ImageView-object that need to access. How do I fix this?
I have had a look at [How to query the child views of a parent view using Titanium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474953/how-to-query-the-child-views-of-a-parent-view-using-titanium) but it doesn't work for me.   I found this, http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/31361/how-to-access-child-view-of-a-tableview-row , it could be a reason for my problem, any clue if this bug has been fixed?

Here is the more detailed code.

```
function (parentView, id, leftMargin) {
var cellImageView = cellImageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    url: imageUrl
});
var cellView = Ti.UI.createView({
    id: id,
    left: leftMargin,
    parent: parentView
});
cellView.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    Titanium.API.info("you clicked1:" + e.source.id);
    OnNumClick(e.source, e.source.parent);
});
cellView.add(cellImageView);
return cellView;
}

OnNumClick = function (cellViewObj) {
Titanium.API.info("cellViewObj:" + cellViewObj);
Titanium.API.info("cellViewObj.children:" + cellViewObj.children);    
};
```

result:
[INFO] [7,10537] cellViewObj:ti.modules.titanium.ui.ViewProxy@437ba5a8
[INFO] [15,10628] cellViewObj.children:null

Comment: are you trying to get the child view in table click event?

Comment: I have added the code (after removing the unwanted parts). I am trying to get the child 'ImageView' of a 'View' -which inturn is child of a 'TableRow'. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: why are you doing this parent: parentView

Comment: I need access to the parentView, without this the parentView returns null. The parentView part handles a different purpose although. Do you see any problem in the way I am trying get the child view? I need access to the (child)ImageView.

Comment: Because parentView is the parent of cellView, so i think you need to access the child view like parentView.cellView.children or something similar.

Comment: so shouldn't cellViewObj.children do the same (i.e. return not null data) given that cellViewObj is not null. (in my result, cellViewObj:ti.modules.titanium.ui.ViewProxy)

Comment: As in my case, i use this code to get the child view in my tableView, myTableView.data[indexOfSection].rows[indexOfRow].children[indexOfChild]

Comment: My bad, I upgraded from Titanium SDK 1.2 to 1.6 (my setup had a problem with 1.6 earlier), and it finally worked. Thanks Muhammad, your last comments helps too. Can you also tell me if I can update the row/child using    myTableView.data[indexOfSection].rows[indexOfRow].children[indexOfChild] = newChildValue (which is a new ImageView)? 

I am having trouble with updating the TableView with new data.

Comment: why are you updating a whole ImageView, just update the image url, and keep the old ImageView.

Comment: yes, just updating the url is advisable (but, it should work both thte ways isn't it?). Here is what I am trying to do:
_tableView.data[0].rows[selectedPosY].children[selectedPosX].imageId = tempImageId;
            _tableView.data[0].rows[selectedPosY].children[selectedPosX].image = tempImageUrl;

Titanium.API.info("imageIdSelected:" + _tableView.data[0].rows[selectedPosY].children[selectedPosX].imageId +
                "imageSelected:" + _tableView.data[0].rows[selectedPosY].children[selectedPosX].image);

The update is done on the data, but it doesn't reflect in UI table, what is missing?

Comment: I even tried doing the below, it is somehow not refreshing the UI table;
_tableView.setData(_tableView.data);
win.add(_tableView);

Comment: This thread is growing too long, I have posted a new question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410010/titanium-refreshing-tableview-with-new-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I upgraded from Titanium SDK 1.2 to 1.6 (for some reason my setup was not working with 1.6 earlier), and it finally worked. Thanks for your help Muhammad.